# Password must be alphanumeric with minimum 8 characters - Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am looking for jquery validation

for : `Password must be alphanumeric with minimum 8 characters`

i wrote following function, but it is accepting 123123A - which is 7 char.

```
function isValid(input) {
    var reg = /^[^%\s]{6,}$/;
    var reg2 = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var reg3 = /[0-9]/;
    return reg.test(input) && reg2.test(input) && reg3.test(input);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to validate again server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this pattern?

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/;
return reg.test(input)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work as expected. `{8,}` refers to 8 or more.

```
function isValid(input) {
    var reg = /^[^%\s]{8,}/;
    var reg2 = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var reg3 = /[0-9]/;
    return reg.test(input) && reg2.test(input) && reg3.test(input);
}
```

This can also help with debugging regular expressions in the future.

http://www.regexr.com/39uq5

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** - Working

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$/;
```